# simplehtmldom scrape pagination of pure javascript

Tags: php, parsing

I am practising using simplehtmldom however I have hit a slight problem, the pagination on the site I am planning to practice on is just javascript and when I turn off javascript it breaks the pagination so it does not display at all (http://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/Intel_Platform_Products/). This is my code so far:

```
<?php 
include('simple_html_dom.php');  

// Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Platform_Products/');

// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('.hot-product-unit') as $article) {
    $item['title'] = $article->find('.productslogan', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
    echo "hello";
    sleep(1);
} 
print_r($articles);
?>
```

This problem is also causing the whole code to break because when there is no javascript the site also shows no product list.

How would I get around this problem?

Thanks for your help,
Marcus